# Number of ways to arrange knights in a round table such that the right of each knight is different than it was last time

Tags: combinatorics

$n$ knights sat for lunch at a round table with $n$ indistinguishable chairs.

In the evening, before dinner, the king asked his assistant to make sure that when the knights sit back at the table for dinner, every knight must not sit on the right of a knight he sat on the right to at lunch.

How many ways can the king's assistant select places for the knights at the table for dinner?

I tried using inclusion-exclusion here but can't really get it right, stuck at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea of inclusion-exclusion works.

Since the chairs are indistinguishable we can fix the position of one particular knight throughout.

Suppose a particular set of $k$ of the knights **are** on the right of the same knight as before. Note that there are   $\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\\\end{pmatrix}$ ways of choosing these knights.

We now have $n-k$ 'blocks' of knights to seat. The block with the 'special' knight is fixed and the number of arrangements is then $(n-k-1)!$ ways. A special case is when $n=k$ and then the number of arrangements is $1$ and **not** $(-1)!$

So, by inclusion-exclusion, the number of arrangements is
$$ (n-1)!-(n-2)!n+(n-3)!\begin{pmatrix}n\\2\\\end{pmatrix}-(n-4)!\begin{pmatrix}n\\3\\\end{pmatrix}+...\pm 1$$